# Push a git repo to Gitlab not using the global settings

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I am trying to push a git repo to Gitlab.

I have --global git and ssh settings that I use for work. The one repo I am having problems with is a personal project so I want to use a different `user.name` and `user.email` git config settings and a different ssh key pair to my global work config.

I have set the `user.name` and `user.email` in the git repo (without the --global switch) using:

```
git config user.name "my gitlab username"
git config user.email "my gitlab registered email address"
```

I have set the git config to use the local ssh key file instead of the system one using:

```
git config core.sshCommand "ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i ~/path-to-ed25519 -F /dev/null"
```

On gitlab I have created a repo with the same name as the local repo and I have added the ssh public key.

Gitlab recommends these commands to push the project:

```
cd existing_repo
git remote rename origin old-origin
git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:project.git
git push -u origin --all
git push -u origin --tags
```

The `git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:project.git` command seems to succeed, no errors at least.
The `git push -u origin --all` command fails with the following output:

```
No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Gitlab recommends testing the ssh setup with `ssh -T git@gitlab.example.com` but it is not clear to me how to populate the example.com from the repo url. I have tried all the obvious combinations but no joy. I have also tried the -i option to specify the private key to use and the -Tvvv option instead of the -T option but it is not clear if this is working. The output looks like:

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "gitlab.com:username/project" port 22
ssh: Could not resolve hostname gitlab.com:username/project: Name or service not known
```

Any and all help appreciated...

Comment: Question title should say "not using" instead of "no tusing". Can't seem to edit my own question. If there is a mod reading please fix and delete this comment too.

Comment: Why not using the same key for both repo ? Other solution, use ssh for your common repositories and use http credential for the specific one.

Comment: I think http is depreciated now? At least Pycharm keeps nagging me about not using it any more.

Comment: `user.name` and `user.email` are not used for authentication (with either ssh *or* https). (rest of comment removed, I see what I misinterpreted now)

Comment: The `ssh` failure at the end is because you ran `ssh -T git@gitlab.com:username/project`; you need `ssh -T git@gitlab.com`, except that if your `core.sshCommand` setting is being respected, you need ssh -T -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i ...` (basically all the options you set here).

Comment: The `No refs in common` error is the main mystery here, as `--all` should have directed your Git to push all branch names. Perhaps you have no branch names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual URL would be:

```
 git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:username/project.git
 # not: 
 git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:project.git
```

Double-check if the remote repository on GitLab is created with a default branch `main`, while your local branch might be `master`.
If that is the case, try instead:

```
git push -u origin master:main
```

Since March 10th, 2021, [GitLab can use `main` for new repositories](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/03/10/new-git-default-branch-name/).

> Every Git repository has an initial branch, which is the first branch to be created when a new repository is generated. Historically, the default name for this initial branch was `master`.
> This term came from Bitkeeper, a predecessor to Git. Bitkeeper referred to the source of truth as the "master repository" and other copies as "slave repositories".
> This shows how common master/slave references have been in technology, and the difficulty in knowing how the term master should be interpreted.
>
> The Git project maintainers, in coordination with the broader community, have been listening to the development community’s feedback on determining a more descriptive and inclusive name for the default branch and offering users options to change the name of the default branch name (usually `master`) of their repository.

Comment: This fixed it: `git push -u origin master:main` ty